# My Sequelize/Node setup wrong? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building a project with Express, trying to use the Sequelize ORM to access a mySQL database.

The errors I'm getting waver between not having models defined and findAll of Orders being a function and not an object I can query.

Is there an obvious flaw in my setup? Thanks!

Order.js:The Model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Order = sequelize.define('stores', {
        index: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        server: DataTypes.STRING,
        gridName: DataTypes.STRING,
        x: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        y: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        z: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        owner: DataTypes.STRING,
        item: DataTypes.STRING,
        deal: DataTypes.STRING,
        quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        price: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        GPS: DataTypes.STRING
    });

    return Order;
};
```

index.js:The model aggregator

```
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
// const config = require(__dirname + '/..database.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
// if (config.use_env_variable) {
//  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
// } else {
sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pw', {
    host: 'ip',
    dialect: 'mysql2'
});
// }

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js';
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

marketRoutes.js:The query controller

```
const models = require('../models');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/api/requestOrders', (req, res) => {
        console.log('hitting route', models.Order);
        models.Order
            .findAll()
            .then(function(orders) {
                console.log(orders);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think marketRoutes.js is looking for models in the wrong place.  Shouldn't you be require index.js, so you can access the models imported from the file system and stored in the db object?

(I use a models directory... but there are some advantages to using sequelize.import)